# Securely sending email via external smtp server in cocoa touch

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I'd like my app to be able to send an email, from my servers to their address, when they press a button. Seems simple enough but I can't seem to find any straightforward examples. The ones I have found use third party libraries which some people said were insecure in that someone could find a way to send their own emails through that account.

Also, would this type of thing get my app rejected? Do I have to use the built in email message window?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this out: http://code.google.com/p/skpsmtpmessage/

Comment: Thanks, I have tried that but 1) wasn't sure if it was secure and 2) got this error when compiling: "_CFWriteStreamWriteFully", referenced from: -[SKPSMTPMessage parseBuffer] in SKPSMTPMessage.o ld: symbol(s) not found"